# Recieving the edit/add data from jqGrid in x-www-form-urlencoded, i need application/json

Tags: java, jquery, json, jqgrid

I am trying to link my jqGrid to my Java Rest service. When i send the edit/add data from jqGrid to my rest in order to process it for DB CRUD operations, i  recieve it like this :

```
"nume=Alin&prenume=Dan&sefDepartament=Yes&position=position+2&joinYear=2015-08-11&oper=edit&id=2"
```

I need to recieve it in a JSON format. How can i achieve that?

This is my Java piece of code :

```
@Path("/update")
public class UpdateDatabase {

@POST
public String updateDatabase(String data){

    System.out.println(data);
}
```

This is my jqGrid settings i have regarding the server connection:

```
 grid.jqGrid({
    pager: '#pager', 
    mtype: "POST",
    url: "/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/fetchData",
    editurl:'/RestWithDatabaseConnection/rest/update',
    datatype: "json",
```

Please let me know if i should add some other information.

Comment: It's unclear which editing mode you use (inline editing, form editing or cell editing). You have to use *different* options depend on the editing mode to set HTTP Content-Type to `application/json` and to format the data using `JSON.stringify`. Moreover it could be important to know, which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: Hey Oleg and thank you for the reply. I am using free jqGrid version 4.11.0 and inline editing mode. How should i procced in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send the results of editing encoded in JSON format one should

1. set `Content-Type: application/json` in the HTTP header
2. use `JSON.stringify` to encode the posted data

If you use free jqGrid then you can use the following `inlineEditing` option, which are the options of jqGrid (in the same level where `editurl`)

```
inlineEditing: {
    ajaxSaveOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    }
}
```

In case of usage old jqGrid versions you can use jqGrid options `ajaxRowOptions` and `serializeRowData` in almost the same way:

```
ajaxRowOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
serializeRowData: function (postData) {
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

Free jqGrid supports `jqGridInlineSerializeSaveData` event as alternative to `serializeSaveData` or `serializeRowData` callback. It's helpful in more advances scenarios. The options `ajaxRowOptions` and `serializeRowData` are supported by free jqGrid too because of the compatibility reasons.

I would recommend you to consider to use free jqGrid 4.12.0 or the latest source from GitHub. The list on main new features and the bug fixes is described in [the readme](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#main-new-features-and-improvements-implemented-in-the-version-4120) as usually.

Comment: Oleg, you're the best! Thank you very much.

Comment: @IvanSt By the way, my congratulation! You have now more as 15 reputation points and have right to vote the content of stackoverflow (about to 30 voting of any answer of question **per day**). It's the most important right, which helps searching engine (even Google) to find really helpful information and not just the text which contains many words like "jqGrid". By voting you will help other people to find really good content. You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was not aware of that. I will make sure to vote up every time i find information i find useful in my studies.